# Configure IntelliJ to comment single line PHP blocks

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I find IntelliJ is usually great at commenting out code when I highlight it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>/</kbd>. It handles commenting Java, Scala, Groovy, HTML, Javascript, Typescript, JSPs, JSFs and GSPs perfectly.

I am now trying to use it to edit Drupal's PHP files, which are full of **single line** PHP blocks. The following is an example. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on the following line:

```php
<?php print render($content['body']); ?>
```

produces:

```php
//<?php print render($content['body']); ?>
```

Can IntelliJ be configured to comment out these single line blocks correctly? Maybe to something like this:

```php
<?php /*print render($content['field_date']);*/ ?>
```

I am using the Ultimate Edition version 12.

Comment: Serious question, what's the difference? It would seem to me that the first option would be (marginally) better as it would not require processing of an empty block.

Comment: @Avery, the first option just wouldn't work. We are talking about PHP snippets embedded in HTML code.

Comment: Of course. Now I feel ridiculous :) Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij in not designed for working with PHP. I don't think you can configure how comments are applied.

Two ideas from me:

- go for [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), JetBrains IDE for PHP, and after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> you'll get:

  `<!-- --> <?php // print render($content['body']); ?>`
- if you want to stick with Intellij, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> one or more times inside `<?php ?>` tags; this will let you select all the contents quickly and then comment them out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for (I was hoping to stick with IntelliJ as I have a license), but you are right.